# Multiple File Upload: Array

Tags: php

```
echo '<pre>';
$img = $_FILES['img'];

if(!empty($img))
{
    $img_desc = reArrayFiles($img);
    print_r($img_desc);

    foreach($img_desc as $val)
    {
        $newname = date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand().'.jpg';
        move_uploaded_file($val['tmp_name'],'./uploads/'.$newname);
    }
}

function reArrayFiles($file)
{
    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file['name']);
    $file_key = array_keys($file);

    for($i=0;$i<$file_count;$i++)
    {
        foreach($file_key as $val)
        {
            $file_ary[$i][$val] = $file[$val][$i];
        }
    }
    return $file_ary;
}
```

.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => pix.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php4Ovz7o
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 6720
        )

)
```

As we can see above, It works on single file but when I upload 4 files it keep loading, checking in browser console network tab showing status pending

And `php.ini` as below:

```
128M > 64M > 32M :: memory_limit > post_max_size > upload_max_filesize
```

Could anyone shed some light on it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't see anything with if(isset($_FILES['myFile'])){}  in there and to debug you should do print_r($_FILES);

Comment: You should have put your form html on here.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this and it works.  I got it from:https://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Multiple-Files-Simultaneous-Upload-Array-Programming-Tutorial

It is all about arrays and either for loops or foreach loops.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="my_parser.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload all files">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my_parser.php

```
<?php
// Script written by Adam Khoury for the following video exercise:
// http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fTsf80RJ5w
if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "upload/".$name_array[$i])){
            echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```